# Inicializar interface

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, interface

Mi duda es sobre las interface. Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando en mi lista se haga la selección de un item, se muestre con los métodos ya creados en la interface e implementada en MainActivity. El problema está en que la interface siempre esta null, al tocar un ítem de la lista me arroja error NullPointerExecption. A continuación os dejo mi código.

```
public interface ActivityComs {

    void onListItemSelected(int position);
}

public class AddressListFragment extends ListFragment {

    private ActivityComs mActivityComs;
    private ArrayList<Contatc> contacts;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        contacts = AddressBook.getInstance().getContacts();
        AddressListAdapter adapter = new AddressListAdapter(contacts);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mActivityComs = (ActivityComs) context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mActivityComs = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        mActivityComs.onListItemSelected(position);

    }

    public class AddressListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contatc> {

        public AddressListAdapter(ArrayList<Contatc> contacts){
        super(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, contacts);

        }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
                if (convertView == null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item , null);
                }

                Contatc currentContact = getItem(position);
                TextView txtName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);

                txtName.setText(currentContact.getName() + " " +currentContact.getSurname());

                return convertView;
            }

        }


}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActivityComs {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dual_fragment);

        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();

        Fragment fragment = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.list_fragment_holder);

        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = new AddressListFragment();
            manager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.list_fragment_holder, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemSelected(int position) {
        if (findViewById((R.id.holder_fragment_details))==null){
            //Portrait
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, PortraitDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("position" , position);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else {
            //Landscape
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

            //Most create two fragments, in case the user have  one open
            Fragment oldFrag = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.holder_fragment_details);
            Fragment newFrag = AddresDetailsFragment.newInstance(position);

            if (oldFrag != null) {
                transaction.remove(oldFrag);
            }

            transaction.add(R.id.holder_fragment_details, newFrag);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

El error en concreto esta en la linea de código:

```
@Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        mActivityComs.onListItemSelected(position);

    }
```

indicando que mActivityComs es null.

Comment: Te muestra null por esta parte de código @Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mActivityComs = null;
}

Answer (score 0):

`MainActivity` implementa la interface `ActivityComs` por lo tanto al inicializar el Fragment `AddressListFragment` agrega `(this)` para inicializar:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dual_fragment);

    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();

    Fragment fragment = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.list_fragment_holder);

    if (fragment == null) {
        //fragment = new AddressListFragment();

        fragment = AddressListFragment.newInstance(this);  //***

        manager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.list_fragment_holder, fragment)
                .commit();
    }

}
```

y modifica el constructor de tu Fragment para que reciba este valor:

```
public class AddressListFragment extends ListFragment {

private ActivityComs mActivityComs;
private ArrayList<Contatc> contacts;


public static AddressListFragment newInstance(ActivityComs activityComs) {
    AddressListFragment myFragment = new AddressListFragment();

    this.mActivityComs = activityComs; //*Inicializa 

    return myFragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    contacts = AddressBook.getInstance().getContacts();
    AddressListAdapter adapter = new AddressListAdapter(contacts);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
...
...
```